# OkHttp ANR at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Stream.waitForIo$okhttp(Http2Stream.kt:716)

Tags: android, okhttp

I am observing a few ANRs in an application I work on. Crashlytics says this is the `Root Blocking` stack trace. Okhttp version used is 4.9.1

```
    RxCachedThreadScheduler-18 (waiting): tid=129 systid=4382
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java)
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:442)
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:568)
       at okhttp3.internal.Util.wait(Util.java:550)
       at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Stream.waitForIo$okhttp(Http2Stream.kt:716)
       at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Stream.takeHeaders(Http2Stream.kt:140)
       at net.danlew.android.joda.TimeZoneChangedReceiver.f(TimeZoneChangedReceiver.java:1)
       at okhttp3.internal.connection.Exchange.readResponseHeaders(Exchange.kt:106)
       at kotlinx.serialization.json.internal.AbstractJsonLexerKt.a(AbstractJsonLexer.kt:25)
       at kotlinx.serialization.json.internal.ComposerForUnsignedNumbers.a(Composers.kt:12)
       at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.kt:34)
       at kotlinx.serialization.json.internal.ComposerForUnsignedNumbers.a(Composers.kt:12)
       at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.kt:95)
       at kotlinx.serialization.json.internal.ComposerForUnsignedNumbers.a(Composers.kt:12)
       at kotlinx.serialization.json.internal.AbstractJsonLexer.a(AbstractJsonLexer.kt:22)
       at kotlinx.serialization.json.internal.ComposerForUnsignedNumbers.a(Composers.kt:12)
       at kotlinx.serialization.json.internal.CreateMapForCacheKt.a(createMapForCache.kt:7)
       at kotlinx.serialization.json.internal.ComposerForUnsignedNumbers.a(Composers.kt:12)
       ...
```

Anyone has an idea on what I should look into.

Comment: If the RxCachedThreadScheduler is ending up calling OkHttp then you might want to use a non blocking form. But your StackTrace looks improbably, I think your deobfuscation is broken. Exchange.readResponseHeaders doesn't call TimeZoneChangedReceiver

Comment: I have the same problem reported on crashlytics, did you find the solution?