# OkHttp3 block on Http2Stream.waitForIo()

Tags: okhttp

```
stackTrace:
java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Stream.waitForIo(Http2Stream.java:645)
at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Stream.takeHeaders(Http2Stream.java:151)
- locked <0x00000006f12faee8> (a okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Stream)
at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2ExchangeCodec.readResponseHeaders(Http2ExchangeCodec.java:136)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.Exchange.readResponseHeaders(Exchange.java:115)
at okhttp3.internal.http.CallServerInterceptor.intercept(CallServerInterceptor.java:94)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:43)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117)
at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:94)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117)
at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:88)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117)
at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:221)
at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:81)
```

version: 3.14.2

Similar feedback:

- [android - OkHttp ANR at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Stream.waitForIo$okhttp(Http2Stream.kt:716) - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70391371/okhttp-anr-at-okhttp3-internal-http2-http2stream-waitforiookhttphttp2stream-kt)
- [Http2Stream blocked forever 3.6.0 · Issue #3246 · square/okhttp · GitHub](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/3246)
- [Sometime may block · Issue #4241 · square/okhttp · GitHub](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/4241)

OkHttp3 source code:

```java
/**
 * Like {@link #wait}, but throws an {@code InterruptedIOException} when interrupted instead of
 * the more awkward {@link InterruptedException}.
 */
void waitForIo() throws InterruptedIOException {
  try {
    wait();
  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt(); // Retain interrupted status.
    throw new InterruptedIOException();
  }
}
```

Comment: No clear answer, but it's likely to be one request being starved on an otherwise healthy shared connection.  So either the request is not getting a response from the server, or the request is "head of line" blocked by another request that is saturating the socket.